# Gerrit and Git workflow

Tags: git, gerrit

I am looking for some advise on how to do this better.
This is the sequence of events:

- Change 1 pushed to server
- Change 1 is modified by the project owner and merged to the master
- I pull the master and get a conflict
- `git reset --hard HEAD~2` to ignore the local changeset and pull again from the master
- or manual merge the conflict and commit again, but in this case my master would be different then the upstream master

What would be the best way to handle this? Now the changes were small but if it gets bigger then I don't think it is a good idea to just delete my last commits.

Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push your changes from a different branch than the one you're tracking on the remote.  That is, only update your local `master` by pulling, and push only from non-`master` branches.  Workflow something like:

```
git co master                        # switch to master branch
git pull                             # update from origin
git co -b work                       # make a working branch
...                                  # work work work
git commit -m "My #1 commit message" # commit
git push HEAD:refs/publish/master    # push to gerrit for publishing on master
...                                  # wait wait wait
git co master                        # switch to master branch
git pull                             # update...
```

etc, etc etc.